# Python Requests failing over integer in cookie

Tags: python, python-requests

So I have a website which has a cookie with an integer in it, causing Requests to fail:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.c1000.nl/kies-uw-winkel.aspx')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 361, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 369, in send
    r = self.build_response(request, resp)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 179, in build_response
    extract_cookies_to_jar(response.cookies, req, resp)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 117, in extract_cookies_to_jar
    jar.extract_cookies(res, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1645, in extract_cookies
    self.set_cookie(cookie)
  File "/srv/www/li/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 270, in set_cookie
    if cookie.value.startswith('"') and cookie.value.endswith('"'):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Is this a bug in Requests? (i.e. shouldn't it be able to handle integers?)
How can I avoid it? Is there a thing in a get request for avoid cookies?

System info:

- Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit
- Python 2.7.3
- Request 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, tracked by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1745). It will be fixed in the next release of Requests.

Comment: The root cause was a Python library bug: [issue 23138](https://bugs.python.org/issue23138). `value` shouldn't be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To handle cookies you should use a session that stores cookies between requests:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://www.c1000.nl/kies-uw-winkel.aspx',timeout=20)
```

This should do the trick. Im not sure why your code sample throws this exception though.. just a quick workaround.

Comment: Hi, it still throws the same error. It's not the problem of saving the cookie between requests but the fact that the cookie has an integer i think. Doesn't it create the same error for you? (i'll add some info about the versions)